# How to replace the UUID with random numbers using Friendly_id gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, friendly-id

Using Rails 4 and FriendlyId Gem version 5.Im new to Friendly id gem. Here I wanna replace my Url like profile-name-{4 (or) 5 length random numbers} instead of profile-name-Long-UUID . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged
   def slug_candidates
      [self.name, "%s %s" % [self.name, SecureRandom.hex(3)]]
   end
end
```

Please click [here](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/576#issuecomment-47485811) for more reference